# letter count in a string, Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

A silly question. I have a piece of code which counts letters appearances in a string lower case and uppercase letters as one. But it returns the hash keys in lower case. I would like to ask how can I make the hash keys return as uppercase letters? And also is there an easy way to put a line between each key? Thank you in forward!

```
downcase.scan(/\w/).inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, c| h[c] += 1;h}
```

Comment: After call to `downcase` there are no more upper-cased letters in a string. And so they are not counted.

Comment: what do you mean `put a line between keys`?

Comment: Never mind stupid me just need to put upcase in the front. :-))) My mistake.

Comment: When it prints out the appearance of the letters. It prints them out like a=>1, b=>2 etc. But I want them in separate lines a=>1 and in a new line b=>2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `upcase` first if you want the letters in uppercase.

Use [each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) instead of [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject). `inject` returns the result of the block and you have to explicitly return the hash in the end. `each_with_object` automatically returns the initial hash.

```
string = "Hello hElLo"
hash = string.upcase.scan(/\w/).each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |char, hash|
  hash[char] += 1
end
puts hash
# => {"H"=>2, "E"=>2, "L"=>4, "O"=>2}
```

To output individual letters and their count on a line each, iterate the hash:

```
hash.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key} => #{value}"
end

# H => 2
# E => 2
# L => 4
# O => 2
```

Comment: Yes it is. My mistake. Is there any way to put every key in a new line?

Comment: Is it better to use each_with_object than inject?

Comment: @user4274735 Yes, it is. Notice with `inject` you always have to return the hash at the end. `each_with_object` is made for such specific cases to save you the hassle.

Comment: @user4274735 check out my gem on word and char counting. It's a text analyser and you can learn a lot: https://github.com/abitdodgy/words_counted

Answer (score 3):

use [**`upcase`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-upcase) instead of [**`downcase`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-downcase)

```
 > string = "HellO hElLo"
 => "HellO hElLo" 

 > string.upcase.scan(/\w/).inject(Hash.new(0)) {|h, c| h[c] += 1;h}
 => {"H"=>2, "E"=>2, "L"=>4, "O"=>2}
```